# Cannot 301 redirect this page to a specific page

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

I want this page:

> http://mystore.com/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fPages%2fHome%2fUser%2fWish-list.aspx

to

> http://mystore.com/en/ukeurope/home

So, I try to write a 301 redirection rule like this:

> RewriteRule ^Login.aspx$ en/ukeurope/home? [R=301,L]

but when I want to try this redirection.
It gives me 404 not Found.

P.S. I don't want another one that is

> mystore.com/Page/Login.aspx

to be redirected by this 301 redirection rule

Comment: Why do you have `en/ukeurope` in your rule if you want to redirect to `mystore.com/home`?

Comment: @RaviThapliyal Edited. Sorry

Comment: When you directly goto: `http://mystore.com/en/ukeurope/home` does it work fine?

Answer (score 1):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+Login\.aspx?ReturnUrl=\%2fPages\%2fHome\%2fUser\%2fWish-list\.aspx [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /en/ukeurope/home? [R=302,L]
```

Comment: +1 I didn't know about THE_REQUEST (so would have probably gone with URI and query string check). But, just to learn, in `/+Login` is `+` required or did you mean `?`?

Comment: `/+Login` means `/Login` or `///Login` since theoretically there can be multiple `/` after domain name also